# Unable to open URL stream

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-io

The code below is for a Google App Engine project.

Why do I get a Stream Closed error without seeing any line returned?

I am definite that the page the URL points to is active.

```
URL url = new URL("http://banico.com.au");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line;

resp.getWriter().println("START");

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    reader.close();
}

resp.getWriter().println("END");
```

Comment: why are you closing the `reader` inside the while statement??

Comment: Gee. That should have been outside of the closing }. I commented out a bunch of things and cleaned it up to present it here. Now I feel stupid. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `reader.close();` outside of the while statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap the BufferedReader instantiation inside a try catch block

or no try this

```
URLConnection urlc=url.openConnection();
```

Comment: It is enclosed in a try catch block, and I added url.openConnection, prior to using the stream into the reader, but I'm still getting the same error...